# Adjusting textfield size in grid

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

Got a GridPane with TextFields in which I want to change the size of them, so they can match they squares the grid creates.

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(50,50,50,50));




                TextField[][] textFields = new TextField[9][9]; 



        //En loop för att generera fältet börjar här
        for(int x =0; x < 9; x++){
            for(int y= 0; y < 9; y++){
                grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black, -fx-control-inner-background; -fx-background-insets: 0, 2; -fx-padding: 2;");
                TextField textField = new TextField("");
                textField.setStyle("-fx-pref-width: 10em;");
                textField.setStyle("-fx-pref-height: 10em;");
                textField.setFont(Font.font("Serif", FontWeight.LIGHT, 20));
                GridPane.setConstraints(textField, y, x);
                grid.getChildren().add(textField);
                textFields[x][y]=textField;
                textFields[x][y].setText("" + KeepingUpWithTheSudokus.getNum(x, y));
//              textFields[x][y].setPrefHeight(100);
//              textFields[x][y].setPrefWidth(20);
            }
        }
```

Tried by using setPrefWidth & Height but left the grid only stretched at the height. Searching for a simple way to change the size.

Comment: [GridPane.setHgrow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHgrow-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.layout.Priority-)?

Comment: Worked out, thanks!!